# Плавное затухание анимации CSS

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

Всем привет. Есть эффект изменения цвета текста при наведении

```css
a{
  color: #000;
}
a:hover{
  transition: 2s;
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a>Lorem</a>
```

Как сделать, чтобы когда убираешь курсор анимация исчезала тоже плавно, а не резко? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перенесите transition в общие стили ссылки

```css
a{
  color: #000;
  transition: 2s;

}
a:hover{
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a>Lorem</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое