# Анимация hover out в css для @keyframes

Tags: html, css, keyframes

У меня есть кнопка, при наведении на нее появляется `box-shadow` и он начинает переливаться, но если отвести курсор от кнопки анимация обрывается.

Мне нужно чтобы анимация постепенно затухала если курсор отвели от кнопки.

Я использую `@keyframes`.

Желательно без `js` и т.д.

Код:

```
.gradient_button_blue{
    font-family: "Acrom_bold";
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: flex;
    width: 13%;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 15px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #40a4f3 , #5161d6);
    background-size: 200% auto;
    transition: all 0.3 linear;
    margin-left: 70px;

}

.gradient_button_blue:hover{
    animation: gr_effect_blue  3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes gr_effect_blue{
    0%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #ffffff;
}

20%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #40a4f3;
}

60%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #5161d6;
}

80%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #40a4f3;
}

100%{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #ffffff;
}
```

}

Comment: код свой покажите

Comment: Я в вопрос добавил код

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857270/Плавное-затухание-анимации-css  возможно этот ответ тебе поможет

Comment: Я уже пробывал, но не получается. Думаю из за @keyframe анимации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Учитывая что плавно убирать анимацию не выходит- единственным верным способом вижу присвоить эту анимацию псевдоэлементу, размеры которого равны размеру самой кнопки и 100% прозрачность. А при наведении на кнопку- плавно увеличивать прозрачность.

```
  .gradient_button_blue {
  font-family: "Acrom_bold";
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 13%;
  height: 46px;
  font-size: 15px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #40a4f3, #5161d6);
  background-size: 200% auto;
  transition: all 0.3 linear;
  margin-left: 70px;

  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;

}

.gradient_button_blue:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  animation: gr_effect_blue 3s infinite linear;

}

.gradient_button_blue:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes gr_effect_blue {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #ffffff;
  }

  20% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #40a4f3;
  }

  60% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #5161d6;
  }

  80% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #40a4f3;
  }

  100% {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #ffffff;
  }
}
```

Comment: Классное решение.

Comment: Спасибо все работает